# Jquery disable input with attr()

Tags: jquery, input, attributes

I have a wired behaviour when I try to disable or readonly a input field using the attr().

`removeAttr('disabled')` is working ok.

`attr('name', 'somthing')` is working

`attr('id', 'something else')` is working

`attr('disabled','disabled')` not working -> it writes only disabled="" in the DOM and it does not disable the input field

`attr('readonly','readonly')` not working -> it writes only readonly="" in the DOM but the input field can still be edited.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name='rdio']").live('click', function() {
        $(".radio_select").find("input[name='rdio']").each(function(){
            if(this.checked)
            {
                $("#"+this.value).removeAttr('disabled');        
            }
            else
            {
                $("#"+this.value).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Has anyone experienced this behaviour? BTW I'm using jquery 1.4.2

EDIT: Sorry, this was something I have tried and forgot to put it back. So with attr() the problem persists.

Comment: I guess `.attribute()` is just a typo?

Comment: `it writes only disabled=""` but is it not working? I mean did the element get disabled or not?

Comment: Reigel. Yes it only writes disabled="" and does not disable the input field. If I manualy (Firebug) add disabled in the value part then it disables the input field.

Comment: After reading this a third time, I still don't know what your problem is. Are you complaining about the missing `value` or does it fail to actually `disable` the element?

Comment: jAndy - It fails to disable the input field.

Comment: @Chris-NTA: I really believe you need to reorder that code. Looks pretty wierd and I'm sure the problem is somewhere inbetween there. Can you please tell what you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be pretty interesting in which browser you experience that behavior. Even more interesting would be to know, if **not working** means, the element does not get disabled, or the attribute is just missing the `disabled` as value.

Due to `W3C` there should not be a value for `disabled` or `readonly`.

So syntatically

```
<select disabled></select>
```

is just fine and correct. No value needed.

Unfortunatly, there is no way to create such a construct with javascript (if you don't want to overwrite the html), so you are forced to add some value. Since both propertys are boolean, you can add pretty much anything. `.attr('disabled', 'foobar')` is just as good as `.attr('disabled', true)`.

Comment: I'm using FF 3.6. This is what I get: disabled="" in the DOM. If you only put disabled in is not working. I guess "disabled" is a attribute and needs a value.

Answer (score 2):

Try using-

```
$('#target').attr("disabled", true);
$('#target').attr("readonly", true);
```

Comment: that `.attribute()` thingy has to be a typo. It would throw an exception and not cause the described behavior.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tried different ways. The only way it works, is when I use purley javascript (document.forms['form'].target.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
attr('disabled', true);
```

and the same for readonly

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` does a good job.

The W3C specification says you have to set the attribute without a value. But thats a jquery attr() function problem. You can't set an attribute without a value.

It writes `disabled=""` in the DOM. But it is working pretty fine.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

Doing `.attr('disabled', true/false);` and the same with `readonly` is the quickest approach. However, do remember that if an element is "disabled" it will not appear in the forms submit data, whereas `readonly` will appear in the post data. This is a common pitfall for developers to want to disable input but then wonder why they don't get their `$_POST` data in PHP.

Just a little heads up !

Answer (score 0):

@OP: I suspect the button is functionally disabled but visually not disabled.

I experienced exactly the same symptoms. Using attr('disabled', 'disabled') yielded disabled="" in the DOM. The button was in fact disabled in that it no longer generated a click event nor submitted the form. However it was still being highlighted as if it were.

The cause was the CSS for the button, which contained the pseudo-selector ':active'. This is being applied even though the button is disabled. Adding ':not([DISABLED])' to active removed the misleading highlighting.

To any Drupal users, the Seven theme has this CSS and Seven is the default administrative theme.

I verified this in FF and Chrome.